# Drop Down Box with list of Colleges in US

Tags: forms, drupal, webforms

I am looking for a combo box to use in a form that has a list of colleges in the US. Any directions where to find those.

Thanks.

Comment: There are at least 2000 of those. I don't think a combo box will provide good usability for that.

Comment: If I can have access to the list, I can check whats the best way to implement it. Where would you recommend looking?

Comment: No idea. I just googled "number of colleges in the united states"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had to scrap bits and pieces from various lists to coming up with a final one. Not sure if its shareable but until there is another resource like Great Schools, official list of colleges will be elusive.

Answer (score 1):

Think I web scraped http://www.utexas.edu/world/univ/alpha/ years ago when I needed a similar list.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I would try to come up with a drop down list from that. It would help to get a combo box though.